# How to remove support for Office 2013 in Outlook Add-in manifest

Tags: outlook-addin, office-js

I have a very basic standard manifest like this:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/manifests

My Outlook Add-in supports the following clients:

- Outlook 2013 or later
- Outlook 2013 Service Pack 1 or later
- Outlook 2016 or later
- Outlook on the Web
- Outlook 2016 for Mac

How do I remove support for Outlook 2013 and leave only 2016?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All apps and add-ins submitted to the Office Store must comply with the [Office Store Validation Policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/store/validation-policies)

Specifically section 4.12.1, "Your add-in must work across all platforms that support the methods that you define in the Requirements element in your add-in manifest." 
For details about which platforms support which methods, see [Office Add-in host and platform availability](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/overview/office-add-in-availability).

Answer (score 1):

As noted above, you MUST support 2013 (even though I think 2013 is EOL in early 2018).  But from my own experience, just make sure this is in your manifest:

```
<!-- These elements support older clients that don't support add-in commands -->
  <FormSettings>
    <Form xsi:type="ItemRead">
      <DesktopSettings>
        <SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://api.franconnect.net/outlook.html?action=upload&amp;view=desktop&amp;mode=read"/>
        <RequestedHeight>450</RequestedHeight>
      </DesktopSettings>
    </Form>
  </FormSettings>
```